# coder Earth problem in speech voice search angular

Tags: angular-ui-router

this is related to voice recog in Angular.

Option 2 is exactly how my code block is formatted (so I can highlight changes in the code) and I'm still getting the error. (And don't get me started on why a heuristic that can fail blocking submission.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { SpeechService } from '../services/speech.service';
import * as speechactions from '../actions/speech';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import * as fromRoot from '../reducers';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-speech',
    templateUrl: './speech.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./speech.component.scss']
})
export class SpeechComponent implements OnInit {

    public _queryControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
    message: any = 'Speak now';
    ticks: any = 0;
    timer: any;
    subscription: any;
    change = false;
    borderheight = 0;
    borderwidth = 0;
    buttoncolor = '#fff';
    miccolor = '#f44';
    resultspage: boolean;
    shadowleft: any = '-69px';
    shadowtop: any = '-68px';

    constructor(
        private speech: SpeechService,
        private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
        private router: Router
    ) {
        this.resultspage = this.router.url.toString().includes('/search');
        if (this.resultspage) {
            this.shadowleft = '-103px';
            this.shadowtop = '-102px';
        }
        this.speechRecognition();
    }

    speechRecognition() {
        this.speech.record('en_US').subscribe(voice => this.onquery(voice));
    }

    onquery(event: any) {
        this.resettimer();
        this.router.navigate([`/search`], { queryParams: { query: event }, skipLocationChange: true } );
        this.message = event;
        const instantsearch = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('instantsearch'));
        if (instantsearch && instantsearch.value) {
            this.router.navigate([`/search`], { queryParams: { query: event }, skipLocationChange: true } );
        }
    }

    hidespeech() {
        this.store.dispatch(new speechactions.SearchAction(false));
    }

    randomize(min, max) {
        let x;
        x = (Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        return x;
    }

    resettimer(recheck: boolean = false) {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        this.timer = timer(0, 100);
        this.subscription = this.timer.subscribe(t => {
        this.ticks = t;
            if (t % 10 === 0 && t <= 20) {
                this.buttoncolor = '#f44';
                this.miccolor = '#fff';
                this.borderheight = this.randomize(0.7, 1);

                if (this.resultspage) {
                    this.borderheight = this.randomize(0.35, 0.5);
                }

                if (!recheck) {
                    this.resettimer(true);
                }
            }

            if (t === 20) {
                this.borderheight = 0;
            }

            if (t === 30) {
                this.subscription.unsubscribe();
                this.store.dispatch(new speechactions.SearchAction(false));
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.timer = timer(1500, 2000);
        this.subscription = this.timer.subscribe(t => {
            this.ticks = t;

            if (t === 1) {
                this.message = 'Listening...';
            }

            if (t === 4) {
                this.message = 'Please check your microphone and volume levels.';
                this.miccolor = '#C2C2C2';
            }

            if (t === 6) {
                this.subscription.unsubscribe();
                this.store.dispatch(new speechactions.SearchAction(false));
            }
        });
    }
}

If you do just that, you'll get your code in and it will even get automatically highlighte
```

```css
.spch {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: left;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  transition:visibility 0s linear 0.218s,opacity 0.218s,background-color 0.218s;
}

.s2fp.spch {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.s2fp .spchc, .s2fp-h .spchc {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 312px;
  max-width: 572px;
  min-width: 534px;
  padding: 0 223px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.spchc {
  display: block;
  height: 42px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.spch {
  text-align: left;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.close-button {
  color: #777;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 26px;
  right: 0;
  height: 11px;
  line-height: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  opacity: .6;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 15px;
}

._o3 {
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  transition: opacity .318s ease-in;
}

._AM {
  height: 165px;
  right: -270px;
  top: -70px;
  width: 165px;
  float: right;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.218s,opacity 0.218s ease-in;
}

.s2tb.spch {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.s2tb .spchc, .s2tb-h .spchc {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 51px 0 85px 126px;
  position: absolute;
}

.s2tb-h ._o3, .s2tb ._o3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 572px;
  transition: opacity .318s ease-in;
}

.s2tb-h ._AM, .s2tb ._AM {
  height: 95px;
  right: -31px;
  top: -27px;
  width: 95px;
}

.s2fp .button, .s2tb .button {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-delay: 0;
}

.s2tb-h ._wPb, .s2tb ._wPb {
  left: 17px;
  top: 7px;
  transform: scale(.53);
}

._CMb {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 301px;
  left: -69px;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -69px;
  width: 301px;
  transform: scale(0.1);
  transition: all .03s ease-in-out;
}

.s2fp-h .button {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transition-delay: 0;
}

.button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: background-color 0.218s,border 0.218s,box-shadow 0.218s;
}

._wPb {
  height: 87px;
  left: 43px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 47px;
  width: 42px;
  transform: scale(1);
}

._AUb {
  background-color: #999;
  border-radius: 30px;
  height: 46px;
  left: 25px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
}

._Fjd {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 53px;
  left: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 52px;
}

._oXb {
  background-color: #999;
  bottom: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  left: 16px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 9px;
  z-index: 1;
}

._dWb {
  border: 7px solid #999;
  border-radius: 28px;
  bottom: 27px;
  height: 57px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 38px;
  z-index: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes typing {from {width:0;}}
.spcht {
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  transition: opacity .1s ease-in,margin-left .5s ease-in,top 0s linear 0.218s;
  -webkit-animation: typing 2s steps(21,end), blink-caret .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-delay: 3.5s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.s2fp-h .spcht, .s2fp .spcht {
  font-size: 32px;
  left: -44px;
  top: -.2em;
  width: 460px;
}

.s2tb-h .spcht, .s2tb .spcht {
  font-size: 27px;
  left: 7px;
  top: .2em;
  width: 490px;
}

.s2tb-h ._gjb, .s2tb ._gjb {
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  .spcht {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: -40%;
  }

  ._AM {
    right: 44px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spch" id="spch" (click)="hidespeech()" [ngClass]="{'s2fp':!resultspage,'s2tb':resultspage}">
  <div class="spchc" id="spchc" >
    <div class="_o3">
      <div class="_AM">
        <span class="_CMb" id="spchl" [style.top]="shadowtop" [style.left]="shadowleft" [style.transform]="'scale(' + borderheight + ')'"></span>
        <span class="button" id="spchb" [style.background-color]="buttoncolor">
          <div class="_wPb">
            <span class="_AUb" [style.background-color]="miccolor"></span>
            <div class="_Fjd">
              <span class="_oXb" [style.background-color]="miccolor"></span>
              <span class="_dWb" [style.border]="'7px solid'+ miccolor"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="_gjb">
        <span class="spcht" id="spchi" style="color:#777">
          {{ message }}
        </span>
        <span class="spcht" id="spchf" style="color:#000"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="close-button">x</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import * as speech from '../actions/speech';

export const MODE_CHANGE = 'MODE_CHANGE';

export interface State {
    speechStatus: boolean;
}

export const initialState: State = {
    speechStatus: false
};

export function reducer(state: State = initialState, action: speech.Actions): State {
    switch (action.type) {
        case speech.ActionTypes.MODE_CHANGE: {
            const response = action.payload;
            return Object.assign({}, state, {speechStatus: response});
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}

export const getspeechStatus = (state: State) => state.speechStatus;
```

Comment: hidespeech: Observable<any>;
 completeQuery$: Observable<any>;
 searchData: String;

 constructor (
  private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
  private router: Router,
  private speech: SpeechService
 ) {
  this.hidespeech = store.select(fromRoot.getspeechStatus);
  this.hidespeech.subscribe(hidespeech => {
   if (!hidespeech) {
    this.speech.stoprecord();
   }
  });